# How to add (sum) items in two columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two columns with a list of Vehicle Types, I want to be add each type of vehicle in both column and display the total number of each vehicle type. I have tried a pivot table but not sure how to get it to add the second column. Thank you in advance for your help.

[image]

Comment: All you need is to use the [COUNTIF](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-countif-function) formula in column D. So your formula for cell D1 would be `=COUNTIF($A$1:$B$9,C1)`

Comment: PeterT Thank you for the reply, I should been more clear with my question and my example, basically I have two columns with names, I want to be able to count in each column how many times a name appears and output a list with the names and the count. I can accomplish this with a pivot table when its only one column but unable with two. Is it possible to create two pivot table for each column and add them together? or another way.

Comment: You can do this `Power Query` (aka `Get&Transform`).  One way is to make each column a separate `Query`.  Then create a new Query using the `Append` operation. Finally, `group by` the resultant column, and use the `Count Rows` function.  All this can be done within the User Interface.